# No time on gnome panel after messing up with system languages (14.04)

Tags: indicator, gnome-panel, time, language-support, panel-applets

I had a few languages installed on my machine. I recently wanted to delete all of them and keep only English. Evidently something went bad in the process, because after deleting them, the applet showing the time on the gnome panel disappeared. I tried several commands but none of them worked.

I tried reinstalling indicator-datetime and language-selector-gnome, and using dconf-tools.

Also tried running:

```
killall unity-panel-service
```

And:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

Resetting its configuration:

```
dconf reset -f /com/canonical/indicator/datetime/
```

I know its running, so it has to be a configurationn problem (I guess):

```
$ ps ax | grep -i indicator-datetime

2863 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service

4043 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep -i indicator-datetime
```